# How to debug RED code?

Tags: debugging, red

What is the preferred way to debug the RED prog lang code? Is there a RED debugger?

Answer (score 2):

There's no debugger AFAIK, but there are functions that can help you with debugging. Take a look at these two articles, they should help you:

- https://github.com/red/red/wiki/Debugging
- https://github.com/red/red/wiki/How-to-Debug:-A-use-case-by-@DocKimbel

Basically you should use inbuilt functions like `probe`, `??`, `dump4`, `stack/dump` or `print-symbol`.

You can also turn various debugging info with `system/preprocessor/debug?: on`, `system/view/debug?: on` and `system/reactivity/debug?: on`.

Comment: these pages point to nowhere: it' shows create a new page